# Calling a global function within a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, so I'm relatively certain I'm missing something here but my googling isn't turning up anything.

```
  var addDate = function(image) {

      // Get the name
      var imName = image.get('system:index');

      //Convert name to date number
      var imDate=imName;
      var dateArray=imDate.split('-');
      var months   = ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
        if (imDate[1]<10) {
          date[1]= imDate[1].slice(1);
        }
      var dateFormatted = months[date[1]] + ' ' + date[2] + ', ' + date[0];

      var dateNum = Date.parse(dateFormatted);

      //set date in metadata
      return image.set({properties: {date_range: dateNum}});
};

image_dated=addDate(image);
```

I get an error:

```
imDate.split is not a function
    in addDate(), line 7
    in <global>, line 20
```

I've confirmed that imName does return a string formatted 'YYYY-DD-MM'.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't have any lines that start with `String.prototype` do you? It's possible to break the `String` object that way. It's nothing a page reload won't fix, but it will keep messing you up if it's still there. By the way that code all by itself runs fine, so you need to look beyond that one function for the issue.

Comment: before return statement, can you put this line and let us know the output - `console.log(typeof string)`

Answer (score 1):

Is because you don't have defined value for string variable, you must define a value and next pass to your function:

```
var myFunction = function(string) {
      return string.split('-');
}

var string='1-2';
var myReturnedValud = myFunction(string);
```

Or passing a value directly as a parameter

```
var myReturnedValud = myFunction('1-2');
```

Additionally, avoid use names like string or number or any type name used by javascript.

```
var myFunction = function(str) {
          return str.split('-');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use String, Number and etc. Use in the arguments another name. For example str, num and etc.

Comment: Expanding on this sound advice: String is the static string object. It's what passes for a String class. That's why you don't use that name as a variable. Same with Number, Array, and others. Note they all start with Capital Letters. If you stick to naming your variables in camelCase where the first letter is lowercase ('c' in camel) and the first letter in each following word in uppercase ('C' in Case) then you'll be fine. Note that this has nothing to do with your issue because you didn't rename any of these variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have run this code on Firefox console and it is working fine

```
var string='1-2';

 var myFunction = function(string) {
      return string.split('-');
 }

myFunction(string);
```